# Web: draw indoor plan by exploiting position of each element from database

Tags: html, web, dynamic, mapping, indoor-positioning-system

Can anyone give me an idea about how to do to get a service web which get position coordinates and draw plan?

Example:

[http://nab17.mapyourshow.com/7_0/floorplan/?hallID=B&selectedBooth=booth~C4325&CFID=7043121&CFTOKEN=37c61349ba1f276-4D13EDE9-FACB-44DA-D76B0F0AFA8C6ACA](http://nab17.mapyourshow.com/7_0/floorplan/?hallID=B&selectedBooth=booth%7EC4325&CFID=7043121&CFTOKEN=37c61349ba1f276-4D13EDE9-FACB-44DA-D76B0F0AFA8C6ACA)

each stand have x,y,width and height saved on the database.